# Neural Network Output

Tags: neural-network, output

I'm working on a dataset that states whether one is positive or negative of diabetes. If in my data set, the number of observations negative of diabetes is 10 times greater than those of my observations positive of diabetes, is it already given that my network would only learn and predict negative of diabetes because it has more observations than that of positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "No, not necessarily".  The longer answer is it depends on how the ANN was trained (some cross-validation scheme), whether it had a sufficiently large sample of each class of data points and what proportion of the population was used as the training set.  You also need to account for type I and type II errors (false positives and false negatives).

Try searching for something like "evaluating classification model" to get in-depth information.